# How do I resolve missing class function in codeigniter?

Tags: php

I have this in my controller:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
use xampp\htdocs\client\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use xampp\htdocs\client\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

But here is the error I am seeing after running the code

```
 Message: Class 'xampp\htdocs\client\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found
    
  Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\client\application\controllers\admin\Home.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have confused `use` and `include`/`require`.

A `use` statement is for [namespace importing and aliasing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). It says "when I use the class name `Foo`, what I actually mean is `Something\Something\Foo`. That full name may look like a Windows file path, but the `\` here is actually PHP's namespace separator, and doesn't directly relate to the location  on disk.

In this case, you would write:

```php
// Alias these class name so I don't have to write them in full in this file
use PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

If you want to reference the code in a particular *file*, you need the [include and require family of keywords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Those say "load this PHP file, and execute the code in it, including class and function definitions.

So the following would make sense:

```php
// Load the file
require_once 'xampp\htdocs\client\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet.php';
require_once 'xampp\htdocs\client\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx.php';
```

However, most PHP libraries are built to be [autoloaded](https://www.php.net/autoload), so you don't have to name each file manually. Generally, you don't even need to configure the autoloading itself, instead you'd use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install them, and it would set up the autoloader for you.

You would then write, in the main entry point of your code:

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

And the classes would be loaded automatically when referenced. Note that you probably still want the `use` lines, though, and those *do* have to be in each file (because each file can use the same alias to reference different classes).

Comment: Thank you very much. The explanation was concise and helpful. I did not spend upto 5minutes before I resolved it using your explanation. Thank you.